# Linux - How to control Winbind Authentication cache timeout

Tags: linux, active-directory, samba, winbind

I have configured my linux machines (running CentOS 5.2) to authenticate against a Windows server running Active Directory. I have even enabled winbind offline logon. Everything works as expected, however I'm also looking to impose a TTL for the winbind authentication cache. So far all I found was the below snippet from the samba documentation

> winbind cache time (G)
>
> This parameter specifies the number of seconds the winbindd(8) daemon will cache user and group information before querying a Windows NT server again.
>
> **This does not apply to authentication requests**, these are always evaluated in real time unless the winbind offline logon option has been enabled.
>
> Default: winbind cache time = 300

Clearly the winbind cache time parameter does not control the cache TTL for authentication requests.
Is there any other way I can implement a cache timeout for winbind authentication requests?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

I was initially using the default `idmap` backend. However, when i switched the `idmap` backend to `AD`, the problem was fixed. Below are the config options i used in **smb.conf**.

```
idmap config MYDOMAIN:backend = ad
idmap config MYDOMAIN:default = yes
idmap config MYDOMAIN:schema mode = rfc2307
idmap config MYDOMAIN:range = 1000-60000

idmap cache time = 1
idmap negative cache time = 1
winbind cache time = 1
```

Note however that i still have to logout and log back in to see any changes that were made on the AD side to group memberships.